# themerolleover jquery theme with scope is not applied to button datepicker

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker, themeroller

I am using Jquery UI in my asp.net application and using "Le Frog" theme.I am trying to customize datepicker using http://jqueryui.com/themeroller. After I customize it and click download I specify mycustomdatepicker as theme folder name and .chenge-a as scope of theme.

I add this html

```
<div id="datepicker" class="chenge-a"></div>
```

and this in jquery

```
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                inline: true
            });
```

and it shows new theme on datepicker

but i want to use it on button click, so i try this html:

```
  <span id="spDate" >
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtdatetemp" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtdatetemp_TextChanged"
        class="txt ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Vacancies, DateRange %>"
            CssClass="chenge-a" OnClientClick="return false;" />
    </span>
```

and write this jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function () {


            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
               // inline: true
            });

            $(".chenge-a").datepicker({
                onSelect: function (value, date) {
                    $(".txt").val(value);
                    $(".txt").change(function () {                       
                        alert('here');
                    }).triggerHandler('change');

                  e.preventDefault();
                }
            });

 });
```

it shows first datepicker in new theme (with scope) where as button datepicker is shown with the old datepicker theme although i have specified .chenge-a as class of the button.

Please suggest why the theme with scope is not applied to datepicker with button ?

Comment: I was able to find this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647260/making-a-programmatically-created-jquery-ui-datepicker-work-with-css-scope

Answer (score 0):

I added this

```
   $("<input type='hidden'/>").appendTo($('body')).datepicker();
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").wrap('<div class="chenge-a" />');
```

and it worked. Reference is

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647260/making-a-programmatically-created-jquery-ui-datepicker-work-with-css-scope
```