# Apply scoped css to dynamically created jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am creating datepicker dynamically on asp.net page on click of button. I have used jquery ui themerollover and a scode for datepicker so that datepicker is styled different than rest of jquery ui controls:

my jquery is like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("<input type='hidden'/>").appendTo($('body')).datepicker();
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").wrap('<div class="chenge-a" />');


            $(".chenge-a").datepicker({
                 numberOfMonths: 2,
                 showCurrentAtPos:1,         
                onSelect: function (value, date) {                   
                    $(".txt").val(value);
                    $(".txt").change(function () {
                    }).triggerHandler('change');
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });


     </script>
```

my html is like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdatetemp" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    ontextchanged="txtdatetemp_TextChanged" class="txt" style="display:none" ></asp:TextBox>


  <span id="spDate">
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server"  Text="<%$ Resources:Vacancies, DateRange %>" CssClass="chenge-a" OnClientClick="return false;" />
                </span>
```

In above jquery I added following lines because it is bug in jquery datepicker that it doesn't pick scoped theme:

```
   $("<input type='hidden'/>").appendTo($('body')).datepicker();
                $("#ui-datepicker-div").wrap('<div class="chenge-a" />');
```

Detail is here:

[Making a programmatically created jQuery UI datepicker work with CSS scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647260/making-a-programmatically-created-jquery-ui-datepicker-work-with-css-scope)

but it has a drawback because when page loads, a datepicker is shown at the bottom of asp.net page. What is better way to apply scoped jquery ui theme to datepicker?

I tried to hide the datepicker using this css

```
.ui-datepicker-inline{display:none !important}
```

but then datepicker is not shown on click of button

Answer (score 0):

I added this class:

.chenge-a .ui-datepicker-inline{display:none !important}

and it worked.